# Validates numericality only if presence (if user fill it), doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I follow some tips to validates the numericality of a field only if presence, with:

```
validates_numericality_of :year, only_integer: true, allow_nil: true
```

or

```
validates_numericality_of :year, only_integer: true, allow_blank: true
```

But I can create it with a year like `'asdfasdf'` and rails stores a blank year.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `allow_nil: true`, use `allow_blank: true`.

You should also replace `text_field` by `number_field` in your view. With `number_field`, if your characters are not only digits, it's evaluated as nil.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it stored in your DB?

Comment: yes @Pierrre-Jean-Bergeron, without :allow_blank, the numericality works as usual.

Comment: Strange, can you try to use `text_field` in your view? And keep `allow_blank` instead of `allow_nil`.

Comment: Correct @Pierre-Jean-Bergeron, with `text_field` works fine, with `number_field` no...

Comment: Great! I added this part to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [api dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_numericality_of), `validates_numericality_of` validates whether the value of the specified attribute is numeric by trying to convert it to a float with Kernel.Float (if only_integer is false) or applying it to the regular expression /\A[+-]?\d+\Z/ (if only_integer is set to true).

That's why in your case it doesn't fail, because the `'asdfasdf'` string is "converted to an integer".

If you remove `allow_nil` then it won't allow to store `nil` values an it will fail:

```
validates_numericality_of :year, only_integer: true
```

If you want it to fail but still allow nil values, you can always use a `before_validate` filter and make it fail there.